# How to implement a jQuery plugin in my server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and web development. I have succesfully implemented other jQuery plugins like data tables or a simple sliders.

I'm having some problems when trying to make this run:
http://jsfiddle.net/KurtWM/pQnPg/

I know that is a must to initialize my code so I did the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#survey1').numericScale();
    } );
</script>
```

I copied the js part exactly as it is from the provided link and uploaded to my server with the name:

```
jquery.numericScale.js
```

I have included jQuery and this plugin in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.numericScale.js"></script>
```

Regarding the HTML part I just copied it into my HTML body.

I really don't have a clue of what could I be doing wrong.

Comment: I would be very happy to help you out, but what exactly is the problem, or error that you are having?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This should work for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>

.survey-wrapper
{
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%; /*height: 500px;*/
  max-width: 640px;
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  border-spacing: 1px !important;
}

ol.survey
{
  list-style: decimal; /*margin-top: 160px;*/
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol.survey > li:last-child
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
}

ol.survey li
{
  padding-left: -20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  border-right: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  border-left: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
}

ol.survey li.alt, ol.survey li:nth-child(even)
{
  background-color: #E8E8E4;
}

.scores > div
{
  background: #E8E8E4;
}

.scores div.alt, .scores > div:nth-child(even)
{
  background-color: #E8E8E4;
}

ol.survey li .opinion-question
{
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol.survey li
{
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

ol.survey li .opinion-responses
{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.0em;
}

ol.survey li .opinion-responses .bipolar-adjective
{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-style: italic;
}

ol.survey li .opinion-responses .response-choice
{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ol.survey li .opinion-responses .response-choice input[type=radio], ol.survey li .opinion-responses .response-choice input.radio
{
}

.scores
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.scores .discipline
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E8E8E4 url(../images/gifts_orange.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.scores .discipline .discipline-name
{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 24px;
  z-index: 200;
  font-family: "Futura Lt BT" , helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.scores .discipline .discipline-total
{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: "Futura Md BT" , helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.scores .selected
{
  background: #1047a9 url(../images/gifts_blue.png) no-repeat 0 0 !important;
}

.scores .selected .discipline-total
{
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}


    .box 
    {
      position: relative;
      width: 60%;
      background: #ddd;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 2em 1.5em;
      color: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
      line-height: 1.5;
      margin: 60px auto;
    }


    .box:before, .box:after 
    {
      z-index: -1; 
      position: absolute; 
      content: "";
      bottom: 15px;
      left: 10px;
      width: 50%; 
      top: 80%;
      max-width:300px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);   
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);    
      -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);   
      -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
      transform: rotate(-3deg);
    }

    .box:after 
    {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
      transform: rotate(3deg);
      right: 10px;
      left: auto;
    }

.rotate
{
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); */ /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}


  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <ol id="survey1" class="survey">
  <li class="question" title="Prophecy">When a situation needs to be corrected I feel a burden to speak up about it in order to correct it.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Shepherd">I feel a special concern for less mature Christians and feel compelled to care for them spiritually.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Teaching">I find it easy and enjoyable to spend time in intensive Bible study.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Encouraging">I am able to help others identify problems and offer solutions.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Giving">I don't understand why others don't give as much and as freely as I do.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Mercy">I am comfortable visiting people who are sick and disabled.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Evangelism">I have greater desire than most to witness to non-Christians.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Administration">If there is no leadership in a group I will step up and take charge.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Serving">I enjoy being called upon to do special jobs around the church.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Prophecy">When issues are being dealt with in a group, I speak up rather than just listening.</li>
  <li class="question" title="Shepherd">I find myself especially concerned that newer Christians will be influenced by false teachers and be harmed in their spiritual growth as a result. </li>
  <li class="question" title="Teaching">Others sometimes accuse me of being too technical or detail-oriented. </li>
  <li class="question" title="Encouraging">I would rather talk personally with someone rather than refer them elsewhere. </li>
  <li class="question" title="Giving">I find myself looking for opportunities to give my money without being asked to give. </li>
  <li class="question" title="Mercy">I have a tendency to think about things for a while before making a decision. </li>
  <li class="question" title="Evangelism">Witnessing to non-Christians comes easily to me. </li>
  <li class="question" title="Administration">I enjoy handling the details of organizing ideas, people, resources, and time in order to have more effective ministry. </li>
  <li class="question" title="Serving">I feel that I am not specifically skilled, but I enjoy doing what needs to be done around the church. </li>
</ol>
</form>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  (function( $ ) {
    $.fn.extend({
        numericScale: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                responseRange:      5,
                topNumber:          3,
                lowOpinionAnswer:  'Lowest',
                highOpinionAnswer: 'Highest'
            };

            var scores = [];        // Array to hold scores
            var key;                // HTML5 localStorage key
            var disciplines = [];   // Array to hold disciplines
            var aHighVals = [];     // Array to hold n highest scores

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);


            // Act on every target list of the plugin.
            return this.each(function() {
                var $list = $(this);
                key = $list.attr('id') + "_key";

                // Replace list items with survey controls.
                $($list).children().each(function(index) {
                    createQuestion($list, $(this), index);
                }).filter(':odd').addClass('alt');

                // Create HTML for survey & scores containers and button 
                $list.wrap('<div id="wrap-' + $list.attr('id') + 
                           '" class="survey-wrapper"></div>');
                $list.after('<div id="scores-' + $list.attr('id') + 
                            '" class="scores"></div>');
                $list.after('<input type="button" id="submitBtn"' + 
                            ' class="button btnStyle" value="Show My Gifts"' + 
                            ' disabled="disabled" />');

                // Hide scores initially
                $('#scores-' + $list.attr('id')).hide();

                loadScores();
                setSubmitBtnState();

                console.dir(scores);

                // ====================
                // Handler:
                // ====================
                $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(e) {
                    // Get the discipline of the question
                    var discipline = $(e.target).closest('li[class~="question"]').attr('data-discipline');
                    var qNum = $(e.target).attr('name').substr(1) - 1;

                    // Replace the question's object property 'value' in the Scores array with the new selection
                    scores[qNum].value = $(e.target).val();
                    storeScores();
                    setSubmitBtnState();
                });

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function storeScores() {
                    var jsonScores = JSON.stringify(scores);
                    localStorage.setItem(key, jsonScores);
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function setSubmitBtnState() {
                    if (getFormFinished()) {
                        $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function getFormFinished() {
                    //var boolFinished = true;
                    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                        if (scores[i].value == 0) {
                            //boolFinished = false;
                            return false;
                            break;
                        }
                     }
                       //return boolFinished;
                        return true;
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function createQuestion(oList, oItem, index) {
                    // Add the 'title' of the list item
                    var title = oItem.attr('title');
                    var qName = "q" + (index + 1);

                    // Create score items in scores Array.
                    createScore(oItem, title, qName);

                    var question = "<div class='opinion-question'>" + 
                        oItem.text() + "</div>" + 
                        "<div class='opinion-responses'>" + 
                        "<span class='bipolar-adjective'>" + 
                        defaults.lowOpinionAnswer + "</span>";
                    // Create a radio button group for each question.
                    for (var i = 1; i <= defaults.responseRange; ++i) {
                        question += "<span class='response-choice'>" + 
                            "<input type='radio' name='" + qName + 
                            "' value='" + i + "' class='radio'";
                        // Create a LocalStorage item for each question.
                        //check if discipline's localstorage is set.
                        if (localStorage.getItem(oList.attr('id') + "_" + qName)) {
                            if (localStorage.getItem(oList.attr('id') + "_" + qName) == i) {
                                question += " checked='checked'";
                            }
                        }

                        // Add required attribute to first radio button in group to allow validation with the jquery.validate.js plugin.
                        if (i == 1) {
                            question += " validate='required:true'";
                        }

                        question += " />" + i + "</span>";
                    }
                    question += "<span class='bipolar-adjective'>" + defaults.highOpinionAnswer + "</span>" + "</div>";
                    oItem.empty().prepend(question).attr('data-discipline', oItem.attr('title')).removeAttr('title');
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function createScore(oItem, d, qName) {
                    var score = {};
                    score.question = qName;
                    score.value = oItem.val();
                    score.discipline = d;
                    scores.push(score);
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function addScoreToPage(score) {
                    if (replace(scores, score.question, score.value)) {
                        var scoreUl = document.getElementById('scores-' + $list.attr('id') + '-ul');
                        var li = document.createElement('li');
                        li.innerHTML = score.question + '; ' + score.value + '; ' + score.discipline;
                        if (scoreUl.childElementCount > 0) {
                            scoreUl.insertBefore(li, scoreUl.firstChild);
                        } else {
                            scoreUl.appendChild(li);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function replace(arrayName, replaceTo, replaceWith) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
                        if (arrayName[i].question == replaceTo) {
                            arrayName.splice(i, 1, replaceWith);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function getHighestScores(oItems, num) {
                    for (var key in oItems) {
                        var obj = oItems[key];
                        for (var prop in obj) {
                        }
                    }
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function surveySetup() {
                    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
                    submitButton.onclick = submitSurvey;
                    if (!window.localStorage) {
                        alert("The Web Storage API is not supported in your browser. You may still submit the form, but your answers will not be saved to your browser.")
                    } else {
                        loadScores();
                    }
                }

                // ====================
                // Handler:
                // ====================
                $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
                    if (!window.localStorage) {
                        alert("The Web Storage API is not supported in your browser. You may still submit the form, but your answers will not be saved to your browser.")
                    } else {
                        submitSurvey();
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("html, body").offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                });

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function submitSurvey() {
                    // Create visual elements for scores.
                    var surveyId = 'div#scores-' + $list.attr('id');
                    var dNumber = 0;
                    var dWidth;
                    var maxHeight = 350;
                    var tallBarHeight = 0;
                    $(surveyId).empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                        if ($('div#' + scores[i].discipline).length == 0) {
                            var dScore = tallyDiscipline(scores[i].discipline);
                            dNumber++;

                            var discipline = {};
                            discipline.name = scores[i].discipline;
                            discipline.value = dScore;

                            disciplines.push(discipline);

                            $(surveyId).append("<div id='" + scores[i].discipline + "' class='discipline'><div class='discipline-name'>" + scores[i].discipline + "</div><div class='discipline-total'>" + dScore + "</div>" + "</div>");
                            if (dScore > tallBarHeight) {
                                tallBarHeight = dScore;
                            }
                        };

                        $(surveyId).show('fast');
                    };

                    //console.dir(disciplines);
                    //return(disciplines);

                    dWidth = 100 / dNumber
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < dNumber; ii++) {
                        $('.scores .discipline').eq(ii).css({
                            'left': Math.floor(dWidth) * ii + '%'
                        });
                        $('.scores .discipline').eq(ii).css({
                            'width': (Math.floor(dWidth) - 1) + '%'
                        });
                        barHeight = Math.floor((disciplines[ii].value / tallBarHeight) * maxHeight)
                        $('.scores .discipline').eq(ii).animate({
                            height: barHeight
                        }, 2000);
                        $('.scores .discipline'); //.addClass('box');
                    };

                    getHighestValues();

                    $list.hide();
                    $('#submitBtn').hide();

                    $('[id*="btnSaveGifts"]').show();
                };

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function getHighestValues() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < disciplines.length; i++) {
                        aHighVals[i] = [disciplines[i].value, disciplines[i].name];
                    }
                    aHighVals.sort(mySorting);
                    aHighVals.splice(defaults.topNumber, aHighVals.length - defaults.topNumber);

                    for (var ii = 0; ii < aHighVals.length; ii++) {
                        $('#' + aHighVals[ii][1]).addClass('selected');
                        $('input[id*="hdnSelectedVals"]').val($('input[id*="hdnSelectedVals"]').val() + aHighVals[ii][1]);
                        if (aHighVals.length - 1 > ii) {
                            $('input[id*="hdnSelectedVals"]').val($('input[id*="hdnSelectedVals"]').val() + ", ");
                        }
                    }
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function mySorting(a, b) {
                    a = a[0];
                    b = b[0];
                    return b == a ? 0 : (b < a ? -1 : 1)
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function tallyDiscipline(discipline) {
                    var total = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                        if (scores[i].discipline == discipline) {
                            total += parseInt(scores[i].value);
                        }
                    }
                    return total;
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function loadScores() {
                    var jsonScores = localStorage.getItem(key);
                    if (jsonScores != null) {
                        scores = JSON.parse(jsonScores);
                        for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                            addScoresToPage(scores[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // ====================
                // Function:
                // ====================

                function addScoresToPage(score) {
                    $('input:radio[name=' + score.question + '][value=' + score.value + ']').attr('checked', 'checked');
                }
            });


        }
    });
})( jQuery );

var disciplines = $('#survey1').numericScale({
  'responseRange' : 5,
  'lowOpinionAnswer' : 'Least like me',
  'highOpinionAnswer' : 'Most like me'
});

console.dir(disciplines);



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've put everything is one file

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this from the end of your jquery.numericScale.js file:

```
var disciplines = $('#survey1').numericScale({
'responseRange' : 5,
'lowOpinionAnswer' : 'Least like me',
'highOpinionAnswer' : 'Most like me'
});

console.dir(disciplines);
```

Add this to your html page after your loaded plugins:

```
<script> 
$('#survey1').numericScale({
'responseRange' : 5,
'lowOpinionAnswer' : 'Least like me',
'highOpinionAnswer' : 'Most like me'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your welcome. Always best to keep it simple!  You should accept an answer. ;-)